# What command to use in SQL

Tags: sql

Im trying to show data from an Employee table and a Buildings table when the employees are in a particular building.

```
Employee table has 'id', 'Forename', 'Surname', 'Buildingid'.
Building table has 'id', 'Name'.

SELECT Employee.Forename, Employee.Surname
FROM Employee
WHERE Employee.Buildingid=1 OR Employee.Buildingid=7;
```

The statements above show the correct employees but I also want to show the corresponding Building name from the Buildings table e.g. 'Buildings.Name' im not sure what command I should be using to complete this?

Comment: You're going to need a `JOIN` of some sort.  Please consult a tutorial appropriate to your DBMS flavor.

Comment: Pupil.Surname - this looks like from another table, not Employee

Answer (score 0):

Use Join:

```
SELECT e.Forename, e.Surname, b.Name as Building_Name
  FROM Employee e
       INNER JOIN Building b on e.Buildingid=b.id
 WHERE e.Buildingid=1 OR e.Buildingid=7;
```

Answer (score 0):

Inner join will do the trick. Here is my SQL query below=>

```
SELECT Employee.Forename, Employee.Surname,  building.name 
FROM Employee 
inner join Building on employee.buildingid=building.id 
WHERE Employee.Buildingid=1 OR Employee.Buildingid=7;
```

Comment: @ato1996 Please let me know if you need any other assistance.